# Facebook's news feed navigation bar for React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I'd like to implement expandable/collapsable navigation + action bars like facebook's feed news does. 
Any advice on how to proceed?

Currently I'm using GTScrollNavigationBar. I can add it natively but it doesn't update immediately and fails because of

```
RCTAssert(self.subviews.count == 1, @"we should only have exactly one subview");
```

in RCTScrollView.

Removing the assertion makes it work but after rotating everything looks funny, it doesn't play well with react.

Thanks!